# Rename [react-vr] to [react-360]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, retag-request

[React VR](https://facebook.github.io/react-vr/) has been renamed to [React 360](https://facebook.github.io/react-360/), so we should map [react-vr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/react-vr) to [react-360](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/react-360).

Comment: Why is this being downvoted? Do we want two separate tags describing the same thing in the future?

Comment: Angular users, perhaps

Comment: It can't be Angular users. They are quite familiar with arbitrary and confusing changes to the names of frameworks.